# Extracting an integer with Volley

Tags: java, android, json, rest, android-volley

[Json image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdXK2.png) I'm trying to extract an integer from a Json Object using Volley and I can't seem to return the value. I tried to extract it as a String (worked for double values) but it's not working for my int value. The Json response and my code is below. it's the "id" I'm trying to retrieve and use as part of building a URL for another network call.

```
[json image link][1]

// parse Json using volley to make network call
private String parseMovieJSON(final String url) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        mMoviesList.clear();


                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject movie = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            //Get json data as strings
                            int id = movie.optInt("id");
                            String posterPath = movie.optString("poster_path");
                            String originalTitle = movie.optString("title");
                            String overview = movie.getString("overview");
                            String releaseDate = movie.optString("release_date");
                            String voteAverage = movie.optString("vote_average");


                            mMoviesList.add(new Movies(id, posterPath, originalTitle, overview, releaseDate, voteAverage));

                        }


                        myMoviesAdapter = new MyMoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, mMoviesList);
                        myMoviesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);
                        myMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {

                if (checkConnection()) {
                    parseMovieJSON(url);

                } else if (!checkConnection()) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mMoviesList = null;

                }


            }

        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
    checkConnection();

    return url;
}


  // network call for Trailers
private void extractTrailer(String s) {


    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, uriBuilder(), null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");


                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject results = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            //Get json data as strings
                            int idNumber = results.optInt(KEY_ID);
                            String movieKey = results.optString(KEY_URL);
                            String movieName = results.optString(KEY_NAME);

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}

private String uriBuilder() {

    // http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/157336/videos?api_key=### (template example)

    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(Constants.BASE_URL).buildUpon();
    builder.appendPath("movie").
            appendPath(String.valueOf(Constants.MOVIE_ID)).
            appendPath("videos").
            appendQueryParameter("api_key", BuildConfig.ApiKey);

    return builder.build().toString();

}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack it's not showing an error. it's just producing an empty value. When i try to build a URL for my other request. It says BasicNetwork.performRequest. I'll add the other network request call that requires that ID below the first one.

Comment: optInt() method doesn't throw an exception, try with getInt() and maybe the stack trace will give more info.

Comment: @SandeepPolamuri good point, I tried that earlier (and again now), no good.

Comment: Does vote_count produce the same result?

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack Nope, vote_count does not produce the same result. I'm so clueless right now :(

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack I see what you were getting at with the vote_count. I manged to extract it as a String and I don't know why.

Comment: Does the same method work for the other field. Do you control the Json file or just consume it

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack Yes, the same method worked for the other fields and I'm just consuming the json file.